# Obter arquivos duplicados em duas listas

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho um relatório com links e preciso obter os duplicados, o problema está em obter os dois locais dos arquivos do file1.html

```
relatorio = ['~/file1.html', '~/pasta/file1.html', '~/file2.html']
```

Codigo:

```
for x in relatorio:
        if x.split('/')[-1] not in unicos:
            unicos.append(x.split('/')[-1])
        else:
            if x.split('/')[-1] not in repetidos:
                repetidos.append(x.split('/')[-1])
```

Resultado:

> Unicos: ['file1.html', 'file2.html']
>
> Repetidos: ['file1.html']

Esperado:

> Unicos: ['~/file2.html']
>
> Repetidos: ['~/file1.html', '~/pasta/file1.html']

Comment: Se você quer o nome completo, por que adicionar na lista `repetidos` apenas o nome do arquivo com `.split('/')[-1]`? É só adicionar o nome completo `repetidos.append(x)`.

Comment: O código está em desenvolvimento e por isso estava incorreto.

Comment: Igor, é isso mesmo o resultado não sai como esperado porque você está adicionado apenas o nome da arquivo com o código ```.split('/')[-1]```. Basta fazer como o Alex mencionou, adicionando nas listas o nome completo do item que está sendo internado no momento.

Comment: Colocando o nome completo o '~/file1.html' ficaria como único e o  '~/pasta/file1.html' como repetido. Tentei uma solução apenas com o nome por isso este "Erro" já que não encontrei. Porem consegui uma outra solução

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução não muito Pytonica é a seguinte:

```
unicos = []
repetidos = []
relatorio = ['~/file1.html', '~/pasta/file1.html', '~/file2.html']

for x in relatorio:
        if x.split('/')[-1] not in unicos:
            unicos.append(x.split('/')[-1])
        else:
            if x.split('/')[-1] not in repetidos:
                repetidos.append(x.split('/')[-1])

for x in relatorio:
     for i in repetidos:
         if x.endswith(i):
             print(x)
```

Resultado:

> '~/file1.html'
>
> '~/pasta/file1.html'

Obs: Essa solução não é ideal pois faz dois loops no mesmo relatório.